# SQL Reporting Services, RTF and a Richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, ssrs-2008

I have a richtextbox (WPF extended toolkit) that I am using in my WPF application to do some text editing. This editing includes bullet points, bold and Italics. I want to know if there is an easy way to represent this in a RDLC (SQL reporting 2008) from c#? Obviously plain text doesn't format this output correctly. Is there a way to use rtf or html?

I am fairly new to this so any examples or suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the report, you can select a placeholder and set the "MarkupType" to HTML.

You can access this same setting in the Placeholder Properties dialog by right clicking on a selected placeholder (text):
[image]